# Does transferring to another website automatically remove session variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, paypal, session-variables

My ASP.Net website uses session variables. If a customer wants to pay for his order using an online payment service (PayPal), my website transfers him to PayPal. Upon payment he is automatically brought back to our website.

The problem is that upon the customer's return to our website, the session variables appear to be removed.

My question is: Does ASP.Net automatically destroy/remove session variables when the ASP.Net website transfers to a different website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if then Session mode is `Inproc` then

> It Will destroy/remove session variables when the ASP.Net website
>   transfers to a different website

Brief

**Session mode="inproc"**
means the session will be stored on the webserver within your application

**Session mode="stateserver"**
means session stores in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service

**Session mode="sqlserver"**
means session will be stored in the database permanently.

**[SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: Which mode should I use if I want to maintain the session variables when I transfer to PayPal and then transfer the user back to our website?

Comment: @RobRoy you can use `StateServer` which stores Session inside another Process on server called ASP.NET State Service. You need to Keep this service on for sustaining session